# How to prevent special characters in UITextField of UIAlertViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uialertviewcontroller

I have `UIAlertViewController` as shown below image.
[image]

here's my code :

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: alertTitle.security, message: "", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
    alertController.addTextField { (textField : UITextField!) -> Void in
        textField.placeholder = placeholder.security
        textField.tintColor = .black
        textField.isSecureTextEntry = true
    }
```

I want to prevent some special characters to insert into `UITextField`.

Comment: Answer : https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/187441/prevent-a-uitextfield-from-being-input-with-aphabetic-characters

Answer (score 2):

You Have to assign the textfield the delegate

```
textField.delegate = self
```

then check check if special character or not

```
 extension ViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
        public func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
            if textField.isFirstResponder {
                let validString = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "!@#$%^&*()_+{}[]|\"<>,.~`/:;?-=\\¥'£•¢")


                if let range = string.rangeOfCharacter(from: validString) {
                    return false
                }
            }
            return true
        }

    }
```

Comment: @UdayBabariya whats not working?,  maybe you forgot to add `textField.delegate = self `.

Comment: -UiAlertViewController do not use the delegate methods of its base ViewController.

Comment: This should only happen if you are subclassing the `UIAlertViewController ` in that case just more your `shouldChangeCharactersIn ` to that `UIAlertViewController`

Comment: Can you add all the relevant code in the question, what exactly are your doing?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help :

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: alertTitle.security, message: "", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
    alertController.addTextField { (textField : UITextField!) -> Void in
        textField.placeholder = placeholder.security
        textField.tintColor = .black
        textField.isSecureTextEntry = true
        textField.delegate = self // new
    }


func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if string == "(special chracter)" {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```